# Online Hadoop connection

Tags: database, hadoop, kerberos

Is there a way to connect to a sample hadoop DB online. I'm trying to test the kerberos connection but I need to test on an actual Hadoop database. I just need to read from the database, is there such service? 
Thanks!

Comment: I haven't tried but you can give it a shot: https://cloudxlab.com/

Search for 'Free Trial' in the given link. You will have to pay a nominal amount as per their description and they will refund it in 5-10 days. It will provide you real-time cluster access for 7 days

Comment: First, Hadoop is not a "DB". It is a full stack of distributed services that can be used, accidentally, to run SQL queries on some data. Second, to test Kerberos auth, you also need access to the same Kerberos KDC that the Hadoop cluster uses; and that's not the kind of things you usually want to expose on the internet.

Comment: On the other hand, you might be able to download a Hadoop "sandbox" with embedded Kerberos auth, and run it in a (large) VM on your (powerful) personal computer.